# How do I access this select value in template file in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, global-variables

I have created drop down list in functions.php file. This list display in header menu of website. My variable name is $user_land_unit. And I want to use that variable in template file. Basically I want to change land unit of each post according to change in that drop down list. So How do I do that?? 
This is my code for drop down

```
<select id="land_unit" name="unit_name" ><?php 
$result=$wpdb->get_results("select * from unit");
                 foreach($result as $row) {
                  $unit_id=$row->unit_id;
                  $unit_name=$row->unit_name;     
                 ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $unit_id; ?>" <?php if($land_unit== $unit_id){ echo 
 'selected="selected"';} ?>><?php echo $unit_name; ?></option>
  <?php  } ?>
</select>
```

**How do I access this select value in template file??**

Comment: the file is called `functions.php`

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're after here, but a lot of times you can just write a function that returns the content you want and call that instead of trying to reference your variable. Otherwise, look at the PHP global declaration.

Comment: I want to change post content according to change in that dropdown list..

Comment: For that, you need ajax

Comment: But how do I access that change value in my template file..